# Get innerHTML value onclick from div (in javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript to change the price value of the div based on the selected div, the price is already defined in the div, if I click on any div it should updated the value in the another div as well. so far I have try below code but it doesn't work, it changes the value of only first div. if I click on another div it repeats the same price value.

Here's the code I have tried so far!

```js
let pricebox = document.getElementById('pricingdata');
const totalprice = document.querySelector("#totalprice");
pricebox.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let mainprice = document.getElementById("pricecad").innerHTML;
  console.log(mainprice);
  totalprice.innerHTML = '$' + mainprice;
});
```

```html
<div class="row text-center pricing-box" id="pricingdata">
  <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
        <h5 class="prdname">Data1</h5>
        <div class="mt-3 value-price">
          <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5" id="pricecad">30</span>
        </div>
        <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
    <div class="card active-plan mb-4">
      <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
        <h5 class="prdname">Data2</h5>
        <div class="mt-3 value-price">
          <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5" id="pricecad">30</span>
        </div>
        <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
        <h5 class="prdname">Data3</h5>
        <div class="mt-3 value-price">
          <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5" id="pricecad">30</span>
        </div>
        <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
        <h5 class="prdname">Data4</h5>
        <div class="mt-3 value-price">
          <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5" id="pricecad">30</span>
        </div>
        <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
    <div class="card mb-4">
      <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
        <h5 class="prdname red-tooltip">All</h5>
        <div class="mt-3 value-price">
          <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5" id="pricecad">69</span>
        </div>
        <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-7">
  <div class="cad-price prd-priceval">Total Price:<strong id="totalprice">$30</strong></div>
</div>
```

Comment: show the html part of this ....

Comment: please be more specific. could you share your html structure as well?

Comment: add your html...

Comment: @MisterJojo please check the updated question

Comment: @polyglot please check the updated question

Comment: hey you should use unique id for each html page. you are using "pricecad" several times.

Comment: @DCR please check the updated question

Comment: @polyglot it's listed on one page, not each HTML page.

Comment: yea i mean you should use 1 unique ID on one page

Comment: there is no `totalprice` in your html

Comment: @MisterJojo it's there, please re check.

Comment: Or to rehprase what polyglot has said, you can't use the same id more than once per page. You have several `id="pricecad"` on your page. Any ID selection you do will only select 1 of these elements.  Use ID when items are unique otherwise use `class` for common styling or data attributes for data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code should work. Click Run code snippet and check the result.

```js
const totalprice = document.querySelector("#totalprice");
const priceboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.pricing-box-cad');
for (var i = 0; i < priceboxes.length; i++) {
  priceboxes[i].onclick = (e) => {
    const mainprice = e.currentTarget.querySelector('.pricecad').innerText;
    totalprice.innerText = '$' + mainprice;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center pricing-box">
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data1</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <span>$</span><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card active-plan mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data2</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <span>$</span><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data3</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <span>$</span><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data4</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <span>$</span><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname red-tooltip">All</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <span>$</span><span class="display-5 pricecad">69</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-7">
                  <div class="cad-price prd-priceval">Total Price:<strong id="totalprice">$30</strong></div>
              </div>
```

Comment: it's not working, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null

Comment: you should update both html and js to make it work. copy my code to your one and test

Comment: pss : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: the code is working fine, however, it's throwing an error when clicking on any div.

Comment: my bad. please replace e.target with e.currentTarget. I updated the code.

Answer (score 1):

1. remove all  `id="pricecad"` as **polyglot** wrote, `id`s must be unique
2. you are looking for event delegation, replace your code by:

```js
const pricebox   = document.getElementById('pricingdata')
  ,   totalprice = document.querySelector("#totalprice")
  ;
pricebox.addEventListener('click', function (e)
  {
  if (!e.target.matches('span.display-5')) return  // ignore clicks else where
  totalprice.textContent = '$' + e.target.textContent;
  });
```

for click on every `.pricing-box-cad'` elements do

```js
const pricebox   = document.getElementById('pricingdata')
  ,   totalprice = document.querySelector("#totalprice")
  ;
pricebox.addEventListener('click', function (e)
  {
  let pricingBox = e.target

  while (!pricingBox.matches('div.pricing-box-cad'))
    {
    if (!pricingBox.parentElement) break
    pricingBox = pricingBox.parentElement
    }

  if (!pricingBox.matches('div.pricing-box-cad')) return  // ignore clicks else where

  totalprice.textContent = '$' +  pricingBox.querySelector('span.display-5').textContent
  });
```

Comment: works fine, but it doesn't update the price when clicking on the main div, if I click on the price it updates the value, but it should change the value when we click on the div

Answer (score 0):

Again using bubbling/delgation, this method uses [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to find the `".pricing-box-cad"` ancestor of the element clicked then gets the element with the price. Note the duplicate IDs have been moved to class.

Also note if you need to support IE (for a start I'm sorry about that!) you will need to use a pollyfill (mentioned in the link above).

```js
let pricingData = document.getElementById("pricingdata");
const totalprice = document.querySelector("#totalprice");

//Set even listener on parent box
pricingData.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  //Find closest pricing box ancestor
  let priceBox = e.target.closest(".pricing-box-cad")
  if(priceBox) {
    let price = priceBox.querySelector(".pricecad").innerText;
    //console.log(price)
    totalprice.textContent  = "$" + price;
  }
  //Alert if clicked outside a pricing box
  else {alert("clicked outside area") }

});
```

```html
<div class="row text-center pricing-box" id="pricingdata">
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data1</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card active-plan mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data2</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">31</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data3</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data4</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname red-tooltip">All</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">69</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="col-7">
                  <div class="cad-price prd-priceval">Total Price:<strong id="totalprice">$30</strong></div>
              </div>
```

Now just for fun, I wanted to see how much I could do in CSS alone with minimal JS. So I came up with the below. This is for demonstration purposes only and is really just to show what you can achieve with minimal JS.

```js
let pricingData = document.getElementById("pricingdata");
const totalprice = document.querySelector("#totalprice");

//Set even listener on parent box
pricingData.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  //Get value from radio button
  let value = this.querySelector("[name=price]:checked").value;
  //UPdate Attribute on price CSS will take care of the rest
  totalprice.dataset.total = "$" + value;
});
```

```css
#pricingdata label  {
  display:block;
}

#pricingdata :checked + label  {
  background-color:#CCC;
}

#pricingdata input[type=radio] {
  display:none;
}

#totalprice:before {
  content : attr(data-total)
}
```

```html
<div class="row text-center pricing-box" id="pricingdata">
      <input type="radio" value="30" id="rdoPrice1" name="price">
      <label for="rdoPrice1" class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data1</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" value="31" id="rdoPrice2" name="price">
      <label for="rdoPrice2" class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card active-plan mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data2</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">31</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" value="30" id="rdoPrice3" name="price">
      <label for="rdoPrice3" class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data3</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" value="30" id="rdoPrice4" name="price">
      <label for="rdoPrice4" class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname">Data4</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">30</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" value="69" id="rdoPrice5" name="price" checked>
      <label for="rdoPrice5" class="col mx-auto pricing-box-cad align-self-center">
        <div class="card mb-4">
          <div class="card-body p-3 text-center">
            <h5 class="prdname red-tooltip">All</h5>
            <div class="mt-3 value-price">
            <sup>$</sup><span class="display-5 pricecad">69</span>
            </div>
            <h6 class="mt-3 interval">YEARLY</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </label>
    </div>

<div class="col-7">
                  <div class="cad-price prd-priceval">Total Price:<strong id="totalprice" data-total="$69"></strong></div>
              </div>
```